# Page id in facebook api fql/places

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to use fql/places api to query places near to my current location. I am not sure what does page id mean in the following query.  The query works fine and returns expected result. However if i dont use page id I get an error.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?   query=SELECT+name%2Cdescription%2Cgeometry%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Ccheckin_count%2Cdisplay_subtext+FROM+place+WHERE+page_id%3D110506962309835&access_token=...
```

Following result was returned

```
Facebook Palo Alto We’re building a web where the default is social. Point -122.15198690595 37.4163458217 37.4163458217 -122.15198690595 657486 Corporate Office・158,101 were here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=65.5833,22.15&distance=1000](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D65.5833%2C22.15%26distance%3D1000)

See [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9579739/facebook-application-that-searches-for-nearest-place/9582039#9582039) for more information on how to find YOUR location.

What you did was to look for location information associated with a specific Facebook Page (in this case Facebook HQ).